# Flutter i want to display the data after searching

Tags: mysql, flutter

[listview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCzh1.jpg)Good day do you have an idea on how to make a search bar that do not show first the list view when no one searching my data is from mysql sorry new at flutter

```
 @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('New Transaction'),
              backgroundColor: Color(0xff083663),
            ),
            body: RefreshIndicator(
              onRefresh: fetchNotes,
              key: _refresh,
              child: loading
                  ? Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    )
                  : ListView.builder(
                      itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                        return i == 0 ? _searchBar() : _listItem(i - 1);
                      },
                      itemCount: _notesForDisplay.length + 1,
                    ),
            ));
      }
```

This is my search bar where the user will input his/her search

```
 _searchBar() {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: Card(
        child: ListTile(
          leading: Icon(Icons.search),
          title: TextField(
            decoration:
                InputDecoration(hintText: "Search", border: InputBorder.none),
            onChanged: (text) {
              text = text.toLowerCase();
              setState(() {
                _notesForDisplay = _notes.where((note) {
                  var noTitle = note.vesselname.toLowerCase();
                  return noTitle.contains(text);
                }).toList();
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

### this is the list view for my search i want this to show after the user inputted a value in the search bar

```
  _listItem(i) {
    final x = _notesForDisplay[i];
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'Vessel Name:\t' + x.vesselname,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                Text('Voyage #:\t' + x.voyageno,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0)),
                Text('Ship Call #:\t' + x.scn,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0)),
                Divider()
              ],
            ),
          ),
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.add_circle_outline,
                size: 30.0,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).push(
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Transaction(x)));
              }),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a `bool` variable that indicate the visibility state of the list view:

`bool _isListViewVisible = false;`

Add it to the `setState` code block:

```
setState(() {
     _isListViewVisible = true; //Or you can check the text length 
     _notesForDisplay = _notes.where((note) {
     var noTitle = note.vesselname.toLowerCase();
     return noTitle.contains(text);
       }).toList();
  });
```

Then put the list in a visibility widget:

```
return Visibility(
   visible: _isListViewVisible,
     child: Container(
       padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
         child: Row(
         children: <Widget>[
            ....
    ],
  ),
));
```

Comment: <?php

include "connect.php";

$queryResult = $con->query("SELECT * FROM vessel_details");

$result = array ();
while($fetchData = $queryResult->fetch_assoc()){
    $result[] = $fetchData;
}
echo json_encode($result);
?>

Comment: great i got it i would like also to add on how to show only the search of the user because after searching it will show all the details in the  table i after searching the list view will be empty again

Comment: how to clear the listview if after searching is done cause after searching all data in the database table will apear

Comment: How do you know the search is done? Do you want to hide the list again when the search is done? @flutterrun

Comment: yes sir or if the user clear the his search bar  the list view will be empty again sir

Comment: When the search is done set the `_isListViewVisible` to false again (using `setState`). Also, you can set it to false when the search bar is empty by checking the length of the changed text in `onChanged` method. @flutterrun

Comment: how to do i check it sir? sorry im new to flutter

Comment: As I said in a code comment you can check text length like this `_isListViewVisible = text.length > 0` or what other limitations you considered.

Comment: ahh i see it i get it now sorry for being a newbie sir can i add another search bar like 3 search bar?

Comment: 3 search bars is a bad ux I think. @flutterrun

Comment: i had posted a new question sir this is my new idea but i dont know how to implement it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64422946/flutter-i-have-a-two-textfields-here-that-i-want-that-can-search-name-and-number

Comment: setState(() {
     _isListViewVisible = true; //Or you can check the text length 
     _notesForDisplay = _notes.where((note) {
     var noTitle = note.vesselname.toLowerCase();
     return noTitle.contains(text);
       }).toList();
  });  how to do i asd a voyage number in my set state that can search both vessel name and number